# iphone wont send imessage to another iphone - sends as sms

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, text

My dad has an iPhone 4. He has his iMessage and group messaging turned on, but when I use iMessage to message him and my mom (who also has an iPhone, as do I), the messages that I send only go through to my mom (i.e. I send a group message to my mom and dad and only my mom gets it). When my mom responds, both my dad and I get the message, so that works normally. I can message my dad directly (not in a group text), but that sends as an SMS (it shows up green vs. blue), even though I have his number stored as an iPhone in my contacts. How can I get it so that I can iMessage him vs send him an SMS? I think once that part of it is fixed I might be able to send him group texts with success.

Comment: Does he have iMessags turned on?  Did he accidentally leave the the group conversation so that he's not getting those messages?

Comment: I don't remember exactly where the pref was in iOS 7, but Settings>iMessage > make sure his iCloud email address is one of the possible receivers, not just the phone number. Might also be worth trying it for a sender too. Experiment ;)

Comment: I tried this sort of stuff. Sorry - I should've mentioned that I tried the basic sort of things like making sure his iMessage and group messaging was turned on.